# Is $\frac{\sin x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$? Is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm said to check if $\dfrac{\sin x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$

I can see that $\dfrac{\sin x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ is continuous on $(0,1].$ So $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1-}\dfrac{\sin x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ is finite.

I need to check if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0+}\dfrac{\sin x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ is finite.

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0+}\dfrac{\sin x^2}{\sin^2 x}\\=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0+}\dfrac{x\cos x^2}{\sin x\cos x}\\=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0+}\dfrac{\cos x^2-2x^2\sin x^2}{\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x}=1$

So uniformly continuous. Am I correct?

Comment: If you're writing this as a solution to a problem, you should explicitly state that you're using l'Hôpital and why it's applicable. If I were writing the solution, I'd further state (and prove!) that $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous precisely when there is a continuous $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ such that $g = f$ on $(a,b)$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using that if a function is continuous on $(a,b]$ and the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow a+}f(x)$ exists, then $f$ (or to be a little pedantic, its extension) is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Can you prove this result? If you can, then you are absolutely right in whatever you have done above.

Comment: If the conditions hold I can prove it to be cont. on $(a,b)$

Comment: You need to prove continuity on the closed interval, it is given to be continuous on the open interval!